# Array#slice(index, length) that fetches elements at the beginning of the array when index+length is out of range

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a compact and readable way to slice an array with an index and a length, but when the index + length is out of range, instead of stopping at the end of the array like

`[ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ].slice(4, 3) #=> ["e"]`

I want to get the elements at the beginning of the array:

`#=> ["e", "a", "b"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
index = 4
length = 3
[ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ].cycle.take(index + length).last(length)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
Array.new(3) { |i| a[(i+4)%a.size] }
# => ["e", "a", "b"]
```

This handles wrap-around:

```
Array.new(10) { |i| a[(i+4)%a.size] }
# => ["e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Enumerator::Lazy`, you can do something like this.
Since `Enumerable#drop` returns an array, you have to use lazy enumerator to handle infinite array. You can use this method if you want to get an array which is wrapped more than once

Works on ruby 2.1.2 .

```
["a","b","c","d","e"].lazy.cycle.drop(4).take(3).to_a # ["e","a","b"]

["a","b","c","d","e"].lazy.cycle.drop(4).take(6).to_a # ["e","a","b","c","d","e"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
[ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ].rotate(4).slice(0, 3) #=> ["e", "a", "b"]
```

Comment: This does not work when the length (`3` in this case) exceeds the length of the array.

Comment: why would the length exceed the length of the array? you're imposing wrap-around when it's not even mentionned in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other one answer using rotate (I used symbol for clarify my answer):

```
(:a..:e).to_a.rotate(4).first(3) #=> [:e, :a, :b]
```